# Refresh webbrowser url from winform

Tags: c#, browser

How can we refresh a WebBrowser from a winform?

I tried this:

```
mymethod()
{
    WebBrowser wbmessages = new WebBrowser();
    Uri myuri = new Uri("http://mysite/message.aspx);
    wbmessages.Url = myuri;
    mypanel.Controls.Add(wbmessages);
}
```

I'm calling this mymethod every 10 seconds with a time ticker event.

In my http://mysite/message.aspx page load event I've printed a unique value like this:

```
System.Guid gid = System.Guid.NewGuid();
Response.Write(gid.ToString());
```

but every time it is showing the same value. What is the problem with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

So you are creating a brand new WebBrowser control every 10 seconds? Sounds like it would quickly consume lots of resources.

Better to keep a reference to your existing control, and simply call the [Refresh](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts4tye44(VS.85).aspx) method on it.

Comment: Even i call the method it is not getting refreshed.. waht is the problem